# Firestore update fails with IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Unsupported type

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-security, google-cloud-firestore

When calling

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("myCollection").document("doc1").update("field1",myObject);
```

I get the error:

> IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Unsupported type: com.myProg.objects.MyObject (found in field field1)

Even though I **can** add myObject to firestore when it is part of myDoc using Set method without a problem.

MyObject class (The simplest example):

```
public class MyObject{
   public int i;
}
```

Edit:
my DB Structure before attempting:

> myCollection ->
>
> ```
> doc1:
>
> field0 - "3"
>
> field1 - null
> ```

also tried it without field1

Comment: If you're still seeking answers for this, can you post the code for the `MyObject` class?

Comment: @BobSnyder added MyObject

Comment: Your post says: _I can add myObject to firestore when it is part of myDoc using Set method_.  Can you post the code for that?  Is `myDoc` another [custom object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#custom_objects) that has an instance of `MyObject` as a member?

Comment: @BobSnyder you are correct

Comment: any solution till now?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So the only way, to update as of now is by using a map. In your case it should look like

```
Map<String, Object> updateMap = new HashMap();
updateMap.put("field1.i", myObject.i);

FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("myCollection")
.document("doc1").update(updateMap);
```

I think Firestore should really update the APIs to facilitate updating of nested objects as a whole.

Answer (score 2):

In my case i wanted to update the complex object in the firestore.

`public class UserInitialModel {
       private List<ServiceItemModel> servicesOffered;
        }`

```
public class ServiceItemModel{
private String serviceName;
private String price;
}
```

it was giving me error when i try to update 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid data. Unsupported type:

I Solved it by by using map

```
List<Map<String,Object>> list=new ArrayList<>();
        for (ServiceItemModel model:
        mUserInitialPresenter.getUserInitialModel().getServicesOffered()) {
            Map<String,Object> servicesOffered=new HashMap<>();
            servicesOffered.put("serviceName",model.getServiceName());
            servicesOffered.put("price",model.getPrice());
            list.add(servicesOffered);
        }
        dataMap.put("servicesOffered",list);
```